# Plymouth splash not working and causing VT problems

Tags: arch-linux, tty, systemd, services

Since I tried installing Plymouth (boot splash), I'm facing two problems :

- It's not working
- My Virtual Terminals (tt1 - 6) aren't working anymore

Here what I did :

1. Added plymouth hook (after base udev and autostart) to mkinitcpio and ran mkinitcpio
2. Defined the theme to be "spinfinity".
3. Disabled slim service and enabled slim-plymouth service.
4. Added splash to kernel parameter in grub.cfg

I already had Intel driver in KMS (i915).

Linux is just booting as it was booting before (HDD alerts => SLiM) and nothing more.
When I'm trying to enter a VT, equally before or after logging, It just displays a blinking cursor (or HDD Alerts for tty1).

How to solve this ?

Comment: Which version of plymouth are you using? The git version may be buggy, because the same problem happened for me. I didn't try the other version because of limitations, but you could try that.